# Drawing a 3D box inside a 3D container box in iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, containers

I want to show the arrangement of number of boxes(ex:10 boxes) inside a 3D container box. The arrangement of boxes also should be in a 3D view. I am a application developer i have no knowledge in OpenGles. Please guide me with the right approach to achieve it.

Is there any OpenGles engines or frameworks (paid or free) available for creating a container of my requirement?

Edit: The expected output is like shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CATransformLayer. It will give you the 2.5D effect. Which would be sufficient to show what you need. You can use https://github.com/joericioppo/3D-Layers as a sample.